# Owl Carousel enable drag while fast scrolling on mobile ios/android

Tags: android, jquery, ios, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I try to drag my carousel while i scrolling fast up/down but it not working in ios/android. Here is my [example](https://codepen.io/kien16/pen/KBOzNo)

```
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoWidth: true,
    center: true,
    items: 3,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10
  });
```

**Step 1:** drag vertical page fast (touch down + fast drag up + touch end)

**Step 2:** while page scrolling then you drag horizontal ( my carousel do not swipe, I think that should end-scrolling and can drag)

How to make my carousel can drag while scrolling, thank

Comment: I don't think so. Drag may happen if you are able to catch owl container but scrolling will not stop I suppose as it is another container... Check out demo page on owlCarousel. They have provided a demo using external library https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/mousewheel.html

Comment: @Akki619 it on mobile not mousewheel

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback to see if the event is fired. In this case, no drag event is fired on the carousel so the Owl Carousel does not receive a drag callback.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    autoWidth: true,
    center: true,
    items: 3,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    onDrag: callback
  });
  function callback() {
    console.log('drag');
  }
});
```

I've tested this functionality of few other carousels too(e.g. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). but none of them have this ability.

It is related to how the browser handles the drag callback and on mobile devices, It is handled this way.